# como receber input do utilizador e escrever num ficheiro

Tags: c, arquivo

Estou a tentar receber várias linhas de input do utilizador(no máximo terão 37 chars cada uma) e escrevê-las num ficheiro, mas o resultado, é a criação do ficheiro sem nada lá.

O meu código atual:

```
void escrever_para_ficheiro(FILE *fp){
    char buffer[37];
    while(fgets(buffer, 37, stdin)){
        fprintf(fp, "%s", buffer);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int main(){
    FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt","a+");
    escrever_para_ficheiro(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Qualquer ajuda seria ótima.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A única coisa que falta em seu código é liberar o fluxo de saída, como a sua instrução while nunca termina você nunca acaba escrevendo no arquivo por isso não aparece nada la, podemos resolver isso com a instrução fflush(NULL), assim todos os dados não gravados que estão no buffer de saída vão ser escritos no arquivo. Não sou especialista mas acho que é essa a explicação.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void escrever_para_ficheiro(FILE *fp){
    char buffer[37];
    while(fgets(buffer, 37, stdin)){

        fprintf(fp, "%s", buffer);

            fflush(NULL);//Aqui a correção
    }
    fclose(fp);
}


int main(){
    FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt","a+");
    escrever_para_ficheiro(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Utilizei o compilador G++.

Comment: de facto funciona, obrigado